# TCP send function retransmission logic?

Tags: tcp, send

When we send a packet and re-transmission starts does we come out of send function or not?
In my case my application took a lock and waits for send to return and then it leaves the lock.

But In my scenario it never came back. I want to know do we really come out of send function when we have a re transmission case?

Answer (score 2):

The send function transfers data into the socket send buffer, blocking while there isn't enough room.

Data is removed from the socket send buffer when acknowledged.

Retransmission starts when data that has been sent to the peer hasn't been acknowledged within the appropriate timeout interval.

The interactions between retransmission and the `send()` function consist basically of this: if data hasn't been acknowledged, it is still in the send buffer, which may cause the `send()` function to block.